# Accumulo Java API Connection/Session

Tags: thrift, apache-zookeeper, accumulo

I wan wondering if anyone knows what exactly happens when a connection is made from JAVA API or thrift to Accumulo.

- Client connection is made to ZooKeepers only?  My understanding is that after a client is authenticated with ZooKeeper, it directly communicates with Master and Tablet Servers from that point on.
- After a client has been authenticated by ZooKeeper, how does client authenticate itself to Master or Tablet Servers, is there a token issued by ZooKeeper to communicate with Master and Tablet Servers.
- When the user ID/password are sent via the Java API, are they sent in clear text to ZooKeeper or are they encrypted in transit?
- When a connection is made via the Java API, is there a session in place with ZooKeeper or with the Accumulo services?  How is the session maintained and how do I get more details about how many sessions are currently in place with Accumulo?
- What kind of encryption does Accumulo use to encrypt the user passwords in ZooKeeper?